# Additional variable passing to converter/ making switchable converter

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, converters

I have buttons which contents are numbers. I change the background colour of buttons with such converter

```
public class RadioBtnToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int k;
            string input = value as string;
            switch (input)
            {
                case "1":
                    return Brushes.Blue;
                default:
                    return Brushes.Red;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

So each button which have 1 in the content is blue, everyone else has red. I want to switch this variable "1" to for example "2", so each button with two in content will have blue background, others red etc. I need to make some kind of switch, maybe passing somehow additional variable to make this switch? but how?

I can make `if` `else` statements instead of switch to make possible checking if passed aditional variable is the same number as selected one to be blue, but how to pass additional variable?

Comment: If the switch value is fixed in XAML, use the `ConverterParameter` property of the Binding. Its value is passed to the `parameter` argument of the Convert method. If the switch value is dynamic, use MultiBinding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IMultiValueConverter` and `MultiBinding`, pass this variable as next object for converting.